# Collar neighbourhoods for topological manifolds.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

The well-known collar neighbourhood theorem states:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with compact boundary $\partial M$, then there exists a neighbourhood of $\partial M$, which is diffeomorphic to $\partial M\times [0,1)$.

I am asking myself if the theorem holds in the topological category. Is it true at least for compact topological manifolds?

My first idea would be to take a more closer look at the work of Kirby and Siebenmann on topological manifolds, but since I am absolutely not an expert in this field, I hoped to get an answer with a reference or a counterexample here.

Answer (score 10):

This is a special case of the main result of this paper:

Morton Brown, "Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds", Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 75 (1962), p. 331-341.

Edit: See also Proposition 3.42 in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" for a self-contained proof of the existence of a boundary collar for manifolds with boundary. Hatcher assumes that the manifold is compact but his proof only uses compactness of the boundary.