# Non-surjective map implies zero degree for manifolds with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

> Let $M$ and $N$ be compact, connected, orientable, topological $n$-manifolds with *non-empty* boundary, and let $$f : (M, \partial M) \to (N , \partial N) $$ be a continuous map of pairs.
> Then, we can define the *degree of $f$* as the integer $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $$f_*([M]) = d[N], $$ where $[M] \in H_n(M, \partial M; \mathbb{Z})$ and $[N] \in H_n(N, \partial N; \mathbb{Z})$ are relative fundamental classes.

> > I am trying to prove/disprove the statement that if $f$ is not surjective, then the degree of $f$ must be zero. I think this is true, however, I am not sure how to prove this.

If $M$ and $N$ would not have boundary, the usual way to prove such a statement would be to use the characterization of the degree by local degrees and regular values. Is there a similar result in the case of non-empty boundary?

I also though about the idea of the proof in the case of spheres: if $y \in N$ is a point not in the image of $f$, then $f$ factors through as a map $$M \to N \setminus \{y\} \hookrightarrow N, $$ but I do not know why this would be the zero map.

Comment: For spheres, it should follow from the observation that $S^n\setminus\{*\}$ is contractible.

Comment: Spheres also have empty boundary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is not surjective, then the degree is necessarily zero.  The way I'll prove this is a follows.  First, I'll show how to turn $f$ into a new map $f'$ between closed oriented manifolds (i.e., they have no boundary) in such a way that $\deg f = \deg f'$.  The process will obviously take a non-surjective $f$ to a non-surjective $f'$.  But for closed manifolds, we already know that $\deg f' = 0$ if $f'$ is not surjective.

So, let's construct $f'$ and the closed manifolds.  I will assume $M$ is oriented, and I'll let $-M$ denote $M$ with the opposite orientation.

Form the space $M' := M\coprod_{\partial M} -M$, where we glue $M$ to $-M$ along their common boundary $\partial M$ via the identity map.  Note that $M'$ is a topological manifold without boundary, and is naturally oriented.  Similarly, form the space $N'$.  Note that $M'$ contains a canonical copy of $M$ and a canonical copy of $-M$, and the the two boundaries, $\partial M$ and $\partial(-M)$ are identified, forming a codimension $1$ embedded submanifold of $M'$.  Similar statements, of course, also apply to $N'$.

Then $f$ induces a map $f':M'\rightarrow N'$ defined as follows.  For $x\in M$, define $f'(x) = f(x) \in N\subseteq N'$.  For $x\in -M$, also define $f'(x) = f(x)\in -N\subseteq N'$.  For $x\in \partial M = \partial (-M)$ (in $M')$, these two definitions agree, so from the pasting lemma, $f'$ is continuous.  Note that if $f$ happens to *not* be surjective, say, missing a point $n\in N$, then $f'$ also misses $n\in N\subseteq N'$, so $f'$ is not surjective either.

Fixing $x\in \partial M\subseteq M'$ and noting that $f(x)\in \partial N\subseteq N'$ we may view $f'$ as either a map $(M',\partial M)\rightarrow (N',\partial N)$ or as a map $(M', x)\rightarrow (N', f(x))$.

We obtain a commutative diagram:

\begin{align*} (M', x) & \xrightarrow{f'} & (N',f(x))\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
(M', \partial M) & \xrightarrow{f'} & (N', \partial N)\\
\uparrow & & \uparrow\\
(M,\partial M) & \xrightarrow{f} & (N,\partial N)\\
\end{align*}

Let's compute $H_n$ of this diagram, where $n = \dim M$.  To that end, note that $H_n(M',\partial M)\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.  Indeed, the quotient map $(M',\partial M)\rightarrow (M'/\partial M, \partial M/\partial M)$ induces an isomorphism since $(M',\partial M)$ is a good pair.  But $M'/\partial M$ is homeomorphic to the one point union $(M/\partial M)\vee (-M/\partial M)$.   Thus $$H_n(M',\partial M) \cong H_n(M/\partial M)\oplus H_n(M/\partial M)\cong H_n(M,\partial M)\oplus H_n(M,\partial M)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}.$$

So, taking $H_n$ of the diagram, we obtain the following diagram: \begin{align*} \mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\deg f'} & \mathbb{Z}\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
\mathbb{Z}^2 & \xrightarrow{f'_\ast} & \mathbb{Z}^2\\
\uparrow & & \uparrow\\
\mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\deg f} & \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

**Proposition**:  We have $\deg f = \deg f'$.

**Proof:**

From the construction, the upward maps send $1$ to $(1,0)$.  Starting in the bottom left corner and moving right then up, we find $1\mapsto \deg f \mapsto \deg f\cdot (1,0)$.
Again starting in the bottom left, but this time moving up then right, we get $1\mapsto (1,0)\mapsto f_\ast(1,0)$, so we see that $f_\ast(1,0) = \deg f\cdot (1,0)$.

If we repeat the construction of the diagram with the bottom spaces replaced by $(-M,\partial M)$ and $(-N,\partial N)$, the upward map sends $1$ to $(0,1)$.  Now the same proof shows that $f_\ast(0,1) = \deg f\cdot (0,1)$.

It now follows that $f_\ast$ is simply multiplication by $\deg f$.

Now let's look at the downward map.  This will send $1$ to $(1,1)$.  Starting with a $1$ in the top left and moving down then right, we find $1\mapsto (1,1)\mapsto \deg f\cdot (1,1)$.  On the other hand, starting with a $1$ in the top left, and then moving right and then down, we find $1\mapsto \deg f' \mapsto \deg f'\cdot (1,1)$.

So, we see $\deg f\cdot (1,1) = \deg f'\cdot (1,1)$, so $\deg f = \deg f'$ as claimed.  $\square$.

Comment: By the way, if someone wants to make my commutative diagrams prettier, please feel free.  I'm used to the diagrams package, but struggled to get that to work here....

Comment: Very neat argument! There’s just something in the computation of $H_n(M,\partial M’)$ that I don’t really understand – why is $H_n(M/\partial M) \oplus H_n(\partial M)$ of rank $2$? The second factor contributes nothing…

Comment: @Aphelli:  There was a typo there (now fixed).  It should have been $H_n(M/\partial M)\oplus H_n(M/\partial M)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you very much for the answer! It is indeed really good. Just one small question: intuitively I see why the double of $M$ is also oriented (if we were to use, say, differential forms), but using homological orientations, why can we define an orientation at the points in $M'$ that are on the boundary of $M$? I recall that an orientation on $M$ is just a (homological) orientation on $M \setminus \partial M$.

Comment: @S.T.:  I admit I was thinking of the smooth case when I wrote it.  Here's a way of making it rigorous.  First, even for topological manifolds,  the boundary has a collar neighborhood (see, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds).  So, instead of gluing $\partial M\subseteq M$ to $\partial M\subseteq -M$ by the identity, we glue neighborhoods together.  Specifically, we take a collar $\partial N\times [0,2)$ in $M$ and glue it to a collar $\partial N\times (-2,0]$ by identifying $(x,t)\in N\times [0,1)$ with $(x,t-1)$ in $(-1,0]$.

Comment: Then, every point in $M'$ has an interior representative in either $M$ or $-M$, so we copy the notion of orientation from that representative.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I understand now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: (M,\partial M) \rightarrow (N,\partial N)$ be continuous nonsurjective. Its image is still compact, so that there is a $y \in N \backslash (f(M) \cup \partial N)$. Write $N’=N \backslash \{y\}$. Let $y \in B \subset N \backslash \partial N$ be a small ball around $y$.

If $H_n(N’, \partial N; \mathbb{Z})=0$, then the conclusion follows.

Now, we have a relative homology LES (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$): $$H_{n+1}(N,N’) \rightarrow H_n(N’,\partial N) \overset{f}{\rightarrow} H_n(N,\partial N) \rightarrow H_n(N,N’).$$

But by excision and the relative homology LES (as $B$ is contractible), $H_k(N,N’) \cong H_k(B,B \backslash \{y\}) \cong \tilde{H}_{k-1}(B \backslash \{y\})$ ($\tilde{H}$ denotes reduced homology). In particular, this group is zero for $k=n+1$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ for $k=n$, so $H_n(N’,\partial N)=\ker{f}$.  But $H_n(N,\partial N)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ too.

The goal is thus to show that $f$ is injective, ie nonzero. But this follows from the definition of the relative fundamental class (see the discussion in Hatcher’s *Algebraic Topology* [online], just above III.3.43).

Comment: I don't immediately see why the last sentence you wrote is true, but let me ask:  is there a version of Poincare-Lefschetz duality for non-compact manifolds with boundary?  Something like $H_n(N',\partial N) = H^0_c(N')$?

Comment: I don’t know about your second question – it would make things simpler, but it’s not stated in Hatcher. For your first question: the fundamental class restricts, by definition, to an orientation (ie a nonzero generator) on $H_n(N,N\backslash \{x\})$ for any $x \in N \backslash \partial N$ – in particular for $y$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: the version of the statement in the encyclopedia of math is indeed that $H_n(N,\partial N)$ is dual to $H^0_c(N \backslash \partial N)$. Since $N \backslash \partial N$ is connected noncompact, the latter space should be zero.

Comment: @Aphelli I do not see why $f$ being non-surjective implies that there is some $y \in N \setminus (f(M) \cup \partial N)$. Could you please explain why such a $y$ cannot be on the boundary of $N$?

Comment: @S.T.:  If if it misses a $y$ in $\partial N$, then, since the image is compact  (hence closed), it misses an open set around $y$.  This open set around $y$ necessarily contains points in the interior of $N$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I see, thank you!