Locally flat knot can be represented by a polygonal knot
Peter Cromwell's Knots and Links states that

[...] when we are considering tame embeddings, we can choose to work in the piecewise linear category without loss of generality [...]

The book then uses this to justify stating that any tame knot is equivalent to a polygonal knot. Prior to this, the proof that polygonal knots are tame is given, but not that tame knots are equivalent to polygonal knots.
Multiple sources define tame knots as those that are equivalent to polygonal knots, but I prefer Cromwell's approach using local flatness as a way to define tameness.

Some definitions:
A knot, $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$, is the image of an embedding $S^1\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$.
A knot is locally flat at a point $p$ if there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$ such that the pair $(U,U\cap K)$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball and one of its diameters. The knot is tame if it's locally flat everywhere.
A knot is polygonal if it is the connected union of a finite number of closed line segments in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (called edges) such that they intersect only at their endpoints (called vertices) and exactly two edges intersect at every vertex.
Two knots $K, K'$ are equivalent if there is an ambient isotopy that maps $K$ to $K'$. That is, if there is a continuous map $h:\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,1] \to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $h_t:= h(\cdot,t)$ is a homeomorphism for all $t\in [0,1]$, $h_0$ is the identity map, and $h_1(K) = K'$.

Theorem: Every tame knot is equivalent to a polygonal knot.
Proof (idea):
Since $K$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, which is compact, then so is $K$. We want to find a finite open covering $\lbrace U_1,\ldots, U_n =: U_0\rbrace$ of $K\setminus S$, where $S = \lbrace p_1,\ldots, p_n =: p_0\rbrace$ is a finite set of points of $K$ (in cyclic order), such that all for all $i=1,\ldots, n$ we have:

$\overline{U_i}$ is convex,
$U_i\cap U_j = \emptyset$ for all $j\neq i$,
$(\overline{U_i},\overline{U_i}\cap K)$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball and one of its diameters, and
$\overline{U_i}\cap\overline{U_{i+1}} = \lbrace p_i\rbrace$.
$\overline{U_i}\cap\overline{U_j} = \emptyset$ for all $j\notin\lbrace i-1,i,i+1\rbrace$.

Then, we can use an ambient isotopy that leaves $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus U_1$ fixed, and maps $U_1\cap K$ to the interior of the segment between $p_0$ and $p_1$. Doing the same for all the $U_i$ we end up with a polygonal knot equivalent to the original one.

My intuition tells me that there are enough open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that such a covering exists, but I cannot prove that that's the case.

Every locally flat submanifold admits a tubular neighborhood which is a disk bundle over the submanifold.

@MoisheKohan could you provide a reference or a proof of this fact?

It is Brown's theorem, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds/703557#703557

@MoisheKohan I have consulted Brown's article, but I was unable to find the statement of your first comment. It seems it deals with collared and bi-collared submanifolds of dimension $n-1$ in manifolds of dimension $n$.

This MO post provides references for tame implies PL. Perhaps an interested individual will write up a sketch of the proof.

@MoisheKohan Once I have the tubular neighborhood, how should I proceed?
